# Problema con método clone copia superficial y profunda Java

Tags: java

```
class Racional implements Cloneable {

private int numerador;
private int denominador;

public Racional(int numerador, int denominador) {
    this.numerador = numerador;
    this.denominador = denominador;
}

public Racional() {
    this.numerador = 1;
    this.denominador = 1;
}

public int getNumerador() {
    return numerador;
}

public void setNumerador(int numerador) {
    this.numerador = numerador;
}

public int getDenominador() {
    return denominador;
}

public void setDenominador(int denominador) {
    this.denominador = denominador;
}

@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}


public class TestClone {
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Racional r1 = new Racional();
    Racional r2 = (Racional)r1.clone();

    if (r1.equals(r2)) {
        System.out.println("r1 equals r2");
    } else {
        System.out.println("r2 not equals r2");
    }
}
```

El resultado es "r2 not equals r2". 
¿Sabéis por qué? Hasta donde yo sé cuando la copia es superficial, se copia los atributos y sus referencias con lo cuál debería de ser equals no?

Gracias de antemano,
Un saludo

Comment: Sobre el uso del método `clone` , tal vez pueda ser de ayuda echar un vistazo en el  "Item 11: Override clone judiciously" en el libro _Effective Java (2nd Edition)_ de Joshua Bloch.

Answer (score 1):

No has implementado `equals`

Si no implementas `equals`, hereda la implementación de `Object`. Y la implementación de `Object` lo que hace es comprobar que las dos referencias apuntan a la misma instancia (`r1 == r2`).